# Renaming dependent library in Android NDK causes UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: android, android-ndk, shared

I'm developing an android app using Android NDK. The JNI layer of app depends on a shared library 'libDependentLib.so'. My android.mk looks like:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(call all-subdir-makefiles)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
TARGET_PLATFORM := 'android-10'
LOCAL_CPP_EXTENSION := .cpp
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti         
MY_LOCAL_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L$(call host-path, $(MY_LOCAL_PATH)/libs) -lDependentLib
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(MY_LOCAL_PATH)/include-all $(MY_LOCAL_PATH)/include
MY_FILES := abc.cpp xyz.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -lm -llog  -lstdc++
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(MY_FILES)
LOCAL_MODULE    := jniLayer
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

My directory structure for libs is:

```
<Android_Project>
       |
     libs----armeabi-----libjniLayer.so
       |       |---------libstlport_shared.so
       |-----------------libDependentLib.so
```

Every time I copy libDependentLib.so to armeabi before running the app. Loading of libs is done as:

```
static {
    try {
        /* loading the libraries */
        System.loadLibrary("stlport_shared");
        System.loadLibrary("DependentLib");
        System.loadLibrary("jniLayer");
    } catch (Throwable th) {
        th.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This runs fine. But due to some requirement, I'm forced to change the external lib name to DependentLib_1. I renamed the same in Android.mk, while loading libs in java and the library name in AndroidProject. But the application fails at System.loadLibrary("jniLayer"); saying

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: link_image[1966]:88 could not load needed library 'libDependentLib.so' for 'libjniLayer.so'    (load_library[1108]: Library 'libDependentLib.so' not found)
```

I'm not able to figure out why still libDependentLib.so is being searched for. I've renamed everything to libDependentLib_1.so. So the same should be looked for. Apart from Andorid.mk and jni loading where libDependentLib.so is being referenced?
Note:Android project contains the new lib

Answer (score 0):

Does your libjniLayer.so is dependent on libDependentLib.so? 
If so you can't rename **libDependentLib.so** because when **libjniLayer.so** is built linker puts name of the dependent .so **(libDependentLib.so)** in the object code. So if you rename libDepenedentLib.so, jniLayer.so will still be looking for libDependentLib.so.